# timezone date to python date

Tags: django, python-3.x

Hi  i am creating ics file for calendar invitation, as far as i see that if i dont put time zone some emails may become conflict, i have checked working ics files from zoom and i see that they put

```
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Turkey Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0300
TZOFFSETTO:+0300
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
```

now i translated this to code like

```
timezone = Timezone()
timezone.add('TZID','Turkey Standard Time')
timezoneStandard = TimezoneStandard()
timezoneStandard.add('TZOFFSETFROM', timedelta(hours=3))
timezoneStandard.add('TZOFFSETTO', timedelta(hours=3))
timezoneStandard.add('DTSTART','16010101T000000') <==== PROBLEM IS HERE
timezone.add_component(timezoneStandard)
cal.add_component(timezone)
```

But i dont know to translate 16010101T000000 , i am getting error *You must use datetime, date, timedelta*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ISO-8601, you can parse this for example with [**`.isoparse`** [readthedocs]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html?highlight=isoparse#dateutil.parser.isoparse) from the [**`dateutil`** package [readthedocs]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You can install this, for example in your local environment with:

```
pip3 install dateutils
```

Then you can parse this with:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import isoparse
>>> isoparse('16010101T000000')
datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

So you can use this in your code with:

```
timezoneStandard.add('DTSTART', isoparse('16010101T000000'))
```